# How to interface with non-standard User store in IdentityServer4?

Tags: asp.net-core, owin, identityserver4

I want to use IdentityServer4 to implement OIDC authentication for future development.  We have an existing homegrown membership schema that was implemented before Asp.Net membership or Aspnet Identity.  We have legacy applications using the existing membership schema to authenticate and authorize users.

How can I implement an adapter that points to the legacy schema, (assume a Users table with username & password columns), for the user store?  The only examples I've seen are InMemory users and AspnetIdentity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To integrate with your own user store you need to create an implementation of `IProfileService` (and optionally `IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator` if you need to use the resource owner grant type), and then register it in `IServiceCollection`.

e.g: `services.AddTransient<IProfileService, GabeFcCustomProfileService>();`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I found a nice [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GkkJ6tqMTC0) that describes exactly how to implement `IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator` and `IProfileService`, but I have an additional question that I hope you can help me with.

Is it possible to add another field to the login form?  Users in our legacy system are identified by company, username, and password.  I need to get company from login to `ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator` in order to uniquely select the user.

Comment: Nevermind, I used the [Quickstart UI](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI) as a basis for modifying the login page and login action on the AccountController to use a value for Company as well as Username and Password.

Answer (score 3):

The legacy system I needed to adapt to IdentityServer4 requires three pieces of information to authentication a user:  company identifier, username, and password.

Our system has a master database with a Companies table that contains connection strings to company-specific databases (tenants).  Each tenant db has a Users table with user profile information including Username and Password.

Using Scott Brady's answer I was able to implement an `IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator` that worked for our situation, but not without digging through the IdentityModel.TokenClient sourcecode.  What I discovered is that the token endpoint (token_endpoint: "http:///connect/token") takes a URL encoded form and serializes the key/value pairs and makes them available in `IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator.ValidateAsync` via the `Request.Raw` property of the `ResourceOwnerPasswordValidationContext` argument.

Here's an example of my `ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator.ValidateAsync()` implementation showing how I authenticate with additional parameters beyond username and password:

```
public Task ValidateAsync(ResourceOwnerPasswordValidationContext context)
{
     _logger.LogInformation("Begin resource owner password validation.");

     var username = context.UserName;
     var password = context.Password;
     var company = context.Request.Raw.Get("company");

     if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(company))
     {
          _logger.LogError("'company' doesn't exist in ResourceOwnerPasswordValidationContext.Request.Raw collection.");
          context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(TokenRequestErrors.InvalidRequest, "Company is required.");
           return Task.FromResult(0);
      }

      if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username))
      {
           _logger.LogError("'username' is null or whitespace.");
           context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(TokenRequestErrors.InvalidRequest, "Username is required.");
           return Task.FromResult(0);
      }

      var userRepo = _userRepositoryFactory.GetUserRepositoryForCompany(company);
      var user = userRepo.GetUserByUserId(username);

      if (user == null)
      {
           _logger.LogError($"No user found for company {company} and username {username}.");
           context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(TokenRequestErrors.InvalidRequest, $"No user {username} found for for {company}.");
           return Task.FromResult(0);
       }

       _logger.LogInformation("Resource owner password validation succeeded.");
        context.Result = user.Password == password ? new GrantValidationResult(context.UserName, GrantType.ResourceOwnerPassword, new [] { new Claim("company", company) }) : new GrantValidationResult(TokenRequestErrors.InvalidRequest, "Invalid username or password.");

        return Task.FromResult(0);
  }
```

I used Postman to verify my results by hitting the token endpoint.  First, I configured a client in my IdentityServer4 implementation:

```
new Client {
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,
    AllowedScopes = {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email
    },
    ClientId = "test.client",
    ClientName = "Test Client",
    ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>
    {
        new Secret("secret".Sha256())
    }
}
```

In Postman I selected Basic Auth for the Authorization Type.  The *Username* is the **ClientId** and the *Password* is the **Client Secret**.  I set the verb to POST and specified a "x-www-form-urlencoded" body.  The endpoint requires minimum values for username, password, grant_type, and scope.  I added a company key/value argument:

[image: Postman body configuration]

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar implementation requirements but wont it be more complaint to use the acr_values header with tenant:company1 as the company identifier ?

Comment: I really don't know much about CORS, but I don't think access control headers would be useful in this context.  

First, I'm not sure that it's an appropriate way to pass an additional identification parameter.  Our users' primary key is effectively company+username.

But also I don't think those headers are accessible from within the `ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator.ValidateAsync()` method.  From the code I posted below, `var company = context.Request.Raw.Get("company");`, Raw is a NameValueCollection that is the contents of the original request's Body.